# How can I tell if my Mac CPU supports AVX?

Tags: cpu

Background info for my particular case (though it would be good if answers were more general):

I have an 11 inch MacBook Pro. I'm trying to run [MuJoCo](http://www.mujoco.org/) but it says `Illegal instruction: 4`. Searching Google for similar errors lead me to something saying that I need a CPU that has [AVX instruction support](http://www.mujoco.org/forum/index.php?threads/error-running-the-simulate.3595/).

When I looked up how to tell if my CPU has AVX support, I came across [this page](https://forums.ubi.com/showthread.php/1888070-Game-Doesn-t-Start-Does-Your-CPU-Support-AVX-Check-Here-To-Find-Out-Forums) which gives a list of CPUs with AVX support.

When I looked up how to tell what CPU my Mac had, Google said to use "About This Mac" which just told me I have a `2.53 GHz Intel Core i5`, but that doesn't seem to be anywhere on the list, but the site says that these types of CPUs tend to support AVX instructions.

How can I tell whether or not my computer actually does support AVX instructions?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Execute this command in Terminal:

```
sysctl -a | grep machdep.cpu.features
```

You'll get a report out like this:

> **Redacted-Family-iMac:~ redacted_user$** sysctl -a | grep machdep.cpu.features
>
> machdep.cpu.features: FPU VME DE PSE TSC MSR PAE MCE CX8 APIC SEP MTRR PGE MCA CMOV PAT PSE36 CLFSH DS ACPI MMX FXSR SSE SSE2 SS HTT TM PBE SSE3 PCLMULQDQ DTES64 MON DSCPL VMX SMX EST TM2 SSSE3 CX16 TPR PDCM SSE4.1 SSE4.2 x2APIC POPCNT AES PCID XSAVE OSXSAVE TSCTMR **AVX1.0** RDRAND F16C

I've bolded the presence of the AXV1.0 CPU feature in the report from my Mac: *iMac 27" Late 2012 3.4GHz Core i7*.

(Answer lifted from [this site](http://csharpmulticore.blogspot.com/2014/12/how-to-check-intel-avx2-support-on-mac-os-x-haswell.html).)

Comment: Strangely, we does it report as AVX1.0? Intel's specifications for my macbook's CPU confirms that AVX2 is supported.

Comment: (From the same source)

You have to run the following command on a Terminal window to check whether AVX2 is listed:

sysctl -a | grep machdep.cpu.leaf7_features